# sending data from client to mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

i'm trying to send form data from react to mysql database through node js / expressjs
now i am getting nothing no error no data

here is server code:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/api/insert", (req, res) => {
  const userName = req.body.userName;
  const userDOB = req.body.userDOB;
  const userEmail = req.body.userEmail;
  const userPassword = req.body.userPassword;

  const sqlInsert =
    "INSERT INTO tblUser (strName,dtmDOB,strEmail,strPassword) VALUES (?,?)";
  db.query(
    sqlInsert,
    [userName, userDOB, userEmail, userPassword],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("record added");
    }
  );
});
```

and here is my client side code  :

```
const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [userPassword, setUserPassword] = useState("");
  const [userEmail, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [userDOB, setUserDOB] = useState("");

  const submitForm = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/insert", {
      userName: userName,
      userDOB: userDOB,
      userEmail: userEmail,
      userPassword: userPassword,
    }).then(() => {
      alert("success");
    });
```

is the problem in axios or express ?
any idea what is going wrong ?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to specify the values of the "INSERT" sql statement as parameters, and have SQL assemble them.  I always assemble the string with all the variables inline (in the "VALUES" portion of the string.)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

`const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO tblUser (strName,dtmDOB,strEmail,strPassword) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";`

Instead of

`const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO tblUser (strName,dtmDOB,strEmail,strPassword) VALUES (?,?)";`

db.js:

```
function query(sql, params, callback) {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection(config.db)
  connection.execute(sql, params, callback);
}
```

index.js:

```
app.post("/api/insert", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  const userName = req.body.userName;
  const userDOB = req.body.userDOB;
  const userEmail = req.body.userEmail;
  const userPassword = req.body.userPassword;

  const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO users (strName,dtmDOB,strEmail,strPassword) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
  db.query(
    sqlInsert,
    [userName, userDOB, userEmail, userPassword],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("record added");
    }
  );
});
```

result:

```
Example app listening at http://localhost:4400
{
  userName: 'aaaabbbb',
  userDOB: 'ddddbbbb',
  userEmail: 'aaaa21@gmail.com',
  userPassword: 'aaaabbbb'      
}
record added
```

Comment: i replace the two ? with four of them still the same problem , what about db.js my db is  ```   const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  password: "admin123",
  user: "admin",
  database: "db",
}); ```

Comment: i think i found out what is the problem im not passing my id but id supposed to be auto increment and its not working and i have to insert it every time any idea how to handle that?

Comment: Does that mean that the id field auto-increment but still doesn't work? Or wouldn't you like to make the id field to auto-increment? would you like to know how to handle id value if it is no auto-increment?

Comment: I think best solution is to make id to auto-increment.

Comment: the id is auto increment but if i did not include it in insert like above it wont insert even it is auto increment . any idea how to handle it in code?

Comment: so yea the id is auto increment but not working and i have to insert values for it